# Error with defval, type & nATRMultip values

Tags: pine-script, undeclared-identifier, errortemplate

I am getting an error with the nATRPeriod type=float option Type mismatch at argument 'defval': expected const string, but got literal float; Type mismatch at argument 'type': expected const string, but got type_error;

Unknown argument 'minval' of type 'literal float';Undeclared identifier 'nATRMultip'; Value with NA type cannot be assigned to a variable that was defined without type keyword. Please help!

```
//@version=3
study(title="IntraScalp", shorttitle="IntraScalp", overlay = true)

//Modified by @TradeEasy
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////INPUTS

nATRPeriod      = input(21, "Period")
nATRMultip      = input(6.3, "Multiplier",type=float, minval=0.5, maxval=1000, step=0.1)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////ATR

xATR = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = na
xATRTrailingStop := 
 iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
  iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
   iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss))) 
                       
pos = na 
pos := 
 iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1, 
  iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
 
color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? lime : blue 
//patr=plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color, linewidth=2, title="ATR Trailing Stop", transp=0)

// Determine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

//Trading
// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
LONG = not isLong and pos == 1


// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short   
SHORT = not isShort and pos == -1


if (LONG)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (SHORT)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

barcolor(isLong ? lime : isShort ? red : na)


// Show Break Alerts
plotshape(SHORT, title="Sell", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, text="Sell", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=red, transp=0)
plotshape(LONG, title="Buy", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, text="Buy", textcolor = white, color=green, transp=0)


// === /PLOTTING ===
// Send alert to TV alarm sub-system
alertcondition(LONG,title="Sell",message="Sell")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////VWMA

len2 = input(100, minval=1, title="Smooth")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = vwma(src, len2)

avg1=avg(out, xATRTrailingStop)
plot(avg1, color=aqua, transp=0, title="ATR")
```

Comment: This code snippet doesn't compile. Please provide a full working script to investigate.

Comment: i have added the complete working script sir, pls check

Answer (score 0):

You had one error in line 60. There was nothing in common with what was described in your question.

```
//@version=3
study(title="Help (IntraScalp)", shorttitle="IntraScalp", overlay = true)

//Modified by @TradeEasy
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////INPUTS

nATRPeriod      = input(21, "Period")
nATRMultip      = input(6.3, "Multiplier",type=float, minval=0.5, maxval=1000, step=0.1)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////ATR

xATR = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = na
xATRTrailingStop := 
 iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
  iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
   iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss))) 
                       
pos = na 
pos := 
 iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1, 
  iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
 
color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? lime : blue 
//patr=plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color, linewidth=2, title="ATR Trailing Stop", transp=0)

// Determine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

//Trading
// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
LONG = not isLong and pos == 1


// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short   
SHORT = not isShort and pos == -1


if (LONG)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (SHORT)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

barcolor(isLong ? lime : isShort ? red : na)


// Show Break Alerts
plotshape(SHORT, title="Sell", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, text="Sell", transp=0, textcolor = white, color=red)
plotshape(LONG, title="Buy", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, text="Buy", textcolor = white, color=green, transp=0)


// === /PLOTTING ===
// Send alert to TV alarm sub-system
alertcondition(LONG,title="Sell",message="Sell")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")
alertcondition(SHORT,title="BuY",message="Buy")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////VWMA

len2 = input(100, minval=1, title="Smooth")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = vwma(src, len2)

avg1=avg(out, xATRTrailingStop)
plot(avg1, color=aqua, transp=0, title="ATR")
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer is complete for you, use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.